# Why can I remember this pitch?

Tags: tone, pitch

I don't have perfect pitch, first of all. However I've realized that for some reason the first note of the song linked below ("Brite Boy" by Alex G) has taken root in my memory such that whenever I see the name of the song pop up on Spotify or YouTube I instantly hear the first note (F#) in my head. I always play the song to check if I'm right and I always am!

Any ideas as to why this particular note has stuck with me? I don't listen to that song an exorbitant amount... And I am usually wrong when I try to remember notes from other songs, even ones I listen to more regularly.

Here's the song:

Comment: Given that you recall that the first note of "Brite Boy" is F# (I listened to the beginning of your linked video and confirmed this), are you *sure* you cannot develop the rest of perfect pitch from this one note alone? (In fact, that's how I started developing perfect pitch - Middle C stuck, and I solidified the rest from there.)

Comment: By the way, I don't think this is a duplicate of the question in Aaron's comment - that one only mentions recalling the song in the correct key but does not mention getting any of the notes right by name, while this question (correctly) identifies the first note by name from memory.

Comment: @Dekkadeci I don't know, it sounds to me like the "Levitin Effect" doesn't *require* pitch-naming, but doesn't preclude it (makes sense; if a subject can recall a starting pitch and then is told "Oh, that's an F#," they now have the ability to replicate an F#).

Comment: @AndyBonner - While I believe that the Levitin Effect *can* possibly be a precursor for developing absolute pitch - and I therefore also believe that the Levitin Effect doesn't preclude pitch-naming - all absolute pitch can require is identifying notes by name without reference pitches. Thus, I believe the question asker could very well have the start of absolute pitch and not just be manifesting the Levitin Effect - therefore, I still don't think this question is a duplicate of the question it's now been tied to.